# How to convert the request as GET in elasticsearch

Tags: http, elasticsearch, httprequest, sense

How to convert this query aggs:

```
{"name_EXACT":{"filter":{"term":{"name":"TS"}}}}
```

into GET request in elasticsearch?

Comment: What do you mean GET request? What are you trying to do?

Comment: when we do in sense plugin we are getting the get method as a post request we need it in the get request format for EG:localhost:9200/_search?q=aggs:{"name_EXACT":{"filter":{"term":{"name":"TS"}}}}

Comment: Aggregations are not supported in `_search?q=` format. That's a limited, query only type of search similar to `query_string`.